# Cloud Datalab permissions - 403 on VM URL when sharing access

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datalab

I've successfully created & hosted a Cloud Datalab VM.
I can access the VM's URL from my account (Project Owner) but my collaborators can't access the *.blogspot.com URL (HTTP 403) unless I give them "Project Owner" permission.

[403 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig8t2.png)

How do I properly share access to the Jupyter server (Cloud Datalab VM) with my team ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to appspot.com URL for the App Engine Flex VM(formerly Managed VM) - such as main-dot-datalab-dot-.appspot.com

The version you have requires minimum editor permissions in the project because a Datalab user can perform tasks beyond those scoped for reader permission. They should not require owner permission.

Separately, we released a beta refresh yesterday so I would urge you to upgrade soon as it fixes issues as well as adds features. See https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/ to get started with the refresh.

Thanks.
Dinesh Kulkarni 
(Product Manager, Datalab)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dinesh

The new, docker-based version does solve this permission-control issue indeed, but I noticed the processing time of my notebook is twice as long if I use your `docker image` instead of `anaconda`.

I also noticed you completely removed the Git repository layer and effectively made notebook sharing a DIY thing.
Do you have any pointers regarding collaboration in the new version of Datalab ?

Comment: This is still happening, but it is difficult to get here as GCP rebranded as a Notebook in their Dataflow Service. Just in case comes handy to anyone.